# Do we need [voting] and [votes] (and [down-votes] and [up-votes]) on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was looking through the tags on Meta and found the tags [voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) and [votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/votes). Sadly neither of them has a tag wiki excerpt nor a full tag wiki. This makes the distinction between the two of them unclear to me, so I decided to have a look at how they are used:

- [votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/votes) has been used for the questions

  - [Why such a low vote turnout? :(](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/why-such-a-low-vote-turnout)
  - [Not Much Voting Going On](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/not-much-voting-going-on)

-> the tag has been used for questions about low amounts of votes happening

- [voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) has been used for the questions

  - [A Suggestion From an Outsider - Vote Early, Vote Often](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/a-suggestion-from-an-outsider-vote-early-vote-often)
  - [Can Writers Graduate? Correlation between voting and progressing?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/can-writers-graduate-correlation-between-voting-and-progressing)
  - [Why such a low vote turnout? :(](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/why-such-a-low-vote-turnout) (which also has the [votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/votes) tag)
  - [How can one evaluate a question's usefulness/research effort?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/844/how-can-one-evaluate-a-questions-usefulness-research-effort)
  - [Why the down-votes?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/why-the-down-votes)

-> the tag has been used for questions about low amounts of votes happening, a discussion about "How to vote in general?" and a discussion about downvotes on a question without any comments

Both tags seem to be used for discussing "Why are there so few votes?", but the [voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) tag seems to have a broader scope where voting in general can be discussed and the way people should vote. [votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/votes) sounds like it's only about the result - the amount of up- or downvotes on a question or answer.

I propose to get rid of the tag [votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/votes) by re-tagging [Not Much Voting Going On](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/not-much-voting-going-on) and removing the tag from [Why such a low vote turnout? :(](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/why-such-a-low-vote-turnout). I would also remove the specific tags [down-votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/down-votes) and [up-votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/up-votes) as they are mainly used on already mentioned questions and [revision edit upvote](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/665/revision-edit-upvote) and [Why all the downvotes?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1074/why-all-the-downvotes) where they can be replaced by [voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting).

Furthermore I propose to change the tag wiki from [voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) to:

Tag wiki excerpt:

> This tag should be used for questions that are related to voting, such as general voting habits of the community, or up- and downvoting patterns on specific questions or answers.

Full tag wiki:

> This tag should be used for questions that are related to voting. These can for example be questions about:
>
> - general voting habits you see of the community, such as low amounts of voting happening on the site in general or high voting on particular topics
> - unusual voting patterns, such as particularly high or low voted questions or answers
> - how voting works on StackExchange, such as how many votes you have per day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those four tags are part of the standard set of tags that every meta site gets on creation.

Other sites in the SE network do have guidance and wikis for them - and they try to emphasize the differences.

For example:
[voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) Peer voting on questions and answers is the primary way users gain reputation.  It also affects the ranking of posts.

[votes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/votes) For questions and discussion regarding the votes on a post or posts. 
 Separate to questions regarding the voting process, see [voting](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting)

[downvotes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downvotes) This tag is for questions specific to downvotes, the community's way of telling peers that their content could be improved. (Downvotes on the meta site may have different meaning).

[upvotes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upvotes) is similar to [downvotes](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/downvotes)

I'm not suggesting that this site should have identical usage to other sites, but we should aim for some common ground with the other sites.

Comment: Oh, good catch -- I hadn't realized these were "standard issue".  Sounds like we need some tag wikis!

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I'll suggest a couple - at least to get things started.  I'm sure they will be improved upon.

Comment: I just approved some wiki edits.  Thanks for helping, and please feel free to propose more!